# Need to append params to each and every log before - in log4j in java

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I need to append my variables to my logger for each and every log.
Has to update the configuration log4J file to update the print statements for every log output. This information should be at the beginning of every log statement.

If you look at one of the log outputs :
"2018-02-02 15:34:43 INFO TestClass:135 - Start time stamp is: 1517585580000 and HHmm is: 1533"
I need to edit the part before the "-"
i.e., 1533 param1 Param2 timestamp 2018-02-02 15:34:43 INFO TestClass:135 -  - Start time stamp is: 1517585580000 and HHmm is: 1533.
Note: the params vary from log to log i can pass them in through logger.info.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using ThreadContext and pattern in log4j2.xml or log4j2.properties file in got expected output. Please find the below piece of code.
log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>

<!--     Console Appender -->
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout
        pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %X{param1} %X{param2} %X{param3} - %m%n" />
    </Console>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

or

log4j2.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %X{param1} %X{param2} %X{param3} - %m%n
```

And

In JAVA file

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Test {
    public static void ThreadContextLoggerCreation(long param1, String param2, String param3) {
        ThreadContext.push(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // Add the fishtag;
        ThreadContext.put("param1", param1);
        ThreadContext.put("param2", param2);
        ThreadContext.put("param3", param3);
        ThreadContext.pop();
    }

    public static void ThreadContextLoggerClear() {
        ThreadContext.clearAll();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
        LogUtil.ThreadContextLoggerCreation(logger, currentTime, customerId, agentLocation, streamId, streamVariant, levelOfDetail);
        logger.info("Current Time of execution(HHmm) is: {}", BatchTimeUtil.convertTimestampToReadableDate(currentTime));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps looking for custom layout. Below articles should help you. In a nutshell, create a custom layout, set up your own conversion characters and handle the log message (& object var args) accordingly to replace conversion characters with appropriate dynamic values.

http://www.wideskills.com/log4j-tutorial/10-custom-appender-and-layout-in-log4j

https://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.in/2010/07/creating-log4j-custom-patternlayout.html

OR

You can try MDC/ThreadContext in log4j/log4j2 for that matter. This will allow you to supply dynamic piece of log information by means of a simple Map & have that available in your log layout using custom patterns strings. Please take a look at below article in this regard -

http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Comment: By using MDC and ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L  %X{param1} %X{param2} %X{param3} - %m%n
I need this configuration in log4j2.xml.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: All you need to do is put the values in MDC (map) before you log your messages and clear it after you have done with it. Please clarify what sort of help you need in this regard.

Comment: I already done with that using MDC(map) in log4j.properties files but the  ConversionPattern not working in log4j2.xml. I need the configuration log4j2.xml.
Any quick solution helps me a lot!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I used ThreadContext and set the required params but unable to get it printed through logger.info. 
But when i tried through EventLogger with StructuredDataMessage then it is appending that params whatever i added to ThreadContext.
I am confused.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class); i used
static Logger logger = LoggerManager.getLogger(Test.class); It is working as expected.